# Missing semicolon in near pointer declaration - microsoft visual c++ 2015/2017/2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using a sdk for a camera (photron) on a visual c++ project, to learn how to use it.
I installed it, added the .lib in the link editor… all of the operation to add a library.
But, when a compile the program, I have a lot of compilation error (arround 1600). Mainly, missing semicolon or undifined type. All of the errors are in the library file, not in my code.
For exemple, I got on this line

```cpp
typedef ADPCMCOEFSET NEAR *NPADPCMCOEFSET;
```

a missing semicolon error (E0065). The compiler seems to expect to have the semicolon right after the NEAR keyword, it's like it think that "NEAR" is the type.

I already had this kind of errors, it was because I used the wrong version of visual c++ to compile the project (the project needed visual c++ 2017 (v141), I used 2019 (v142)).
So, I tried to compile my test project with v140 (2015), v141 and v142. But, I still have all those errors.

The library seems to be old, so I thought that maybe I need to use visual c++ 2013 to compile it (it is the last version mentioned in the documentation), but it isn't available in visual studio installer.
Or maybe I missed something ? Is there a solution to compile my program with this library ?

Also, when I am browsing the files containing the errors, some undifined type errors just disapear !

Comment: The problem is unlikely to be with the compiler version. You probably need a set of platform-specific compiler flags to build your project. You need to read the documentation that comes with the library in order to figure it out. Either that or you are directly `#uinclude`ing an internal header that is not meant for the user. NEAR is probably meant to be a macro `#define`d either in a header fike or in the compiler flags. If all else fails, add such a definiton for NEAR to expand to an empty string.

Comment: I think you will need to read the Barcelona romance novel that comes with the SDK.  It is called Manual.